# Number conversion issue

Tags: c, bluetooth

I'm generating a random integer (between 0 & 99), converting it into a string and successfully transferring it over bluetooth to a second machine, which then converts it back to an integer for further processing. However any subsequent calculations result in an answer of 0. I'm using: -

```
str_int = strtol(buf, NULL, 10);
```

But when I then try to: -

```
height = (str_int / 100);
```

The answer is always 0. What am I missing? I need to eventually scale this random number between -0.5 and 0.5 for OpenGL processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming height is a float or double:

```
height = (str_int / 100.0);
```

Integer division in C always truncates to an integer before assigning it to your variable. Putting a `.0` at the end of the number informs the compiler that you want that number to be interpreted as a `double` and hence the compiler will interpret the expression as a floating point division.

Comment: I'm wondering if the first operand isn't determining the operation type...